# Textbox and AJAX data from mySQL

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Hello I have a textbox and when I type something in it should update the page with the mySQL data via AJAX.

So Im trying to get live updated database results whenever you type something in the textbox. The goal is to get a textbox that is getting data from the mySQL database.

I have written the code so far, hopefully someone can advise me in this mather, thank you.

```
$select = 'SELECT *';
$from = ' FROM overboekingen';

$where2 = ' WHERE naam_klant LIKE % . $val . % ';

$opts = (isset($_POST['filterOpts']) ? $_POST['filterOpts'] : FALSE);  
$val = (isset($_POST['txt']) ? $_POST['txt'] : FALSE);

  if (is_array($opts) || $val)  {

    $where = ' WHERE FALSE';

   if (in_array("naam_klant", $val)){
   $where2.val;
  }

}

else {

$where = false;

}

$sql = $select . $from . $where;
$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json = json_encode($results);
echo($json);
?>
```

**AJAX**

```
function updateEmployeesText(val){
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "submit.php",
    dataType : 'json',
    cache: false,
    data: {text: val},
    success: function(records){
        $('#employees tbody').html(makeTable(records));
    }
}); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must define the PHP $val variable before.

The correct sytax:

```
$where2 = " WHERE naam_klant LIKE %$val% ";
```

Comment: I tryed your advise but it does not chance the outcome.

Comment: your php $results is ok?

Comment: Yes that is working fine, it has to do with: $val = (isset($_POST['txt']) ? $_POST['txt'] : FALSE);

  if (is_array($opts) || $val)  {

    $where = ' WHERE FALSE';

   if (in_array("naam_klant", $val)){
   $where2.val;
  }

Comment: check this [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) how to use json_encode in PHP. I think your Ajax script also incorrect.